# Regex in kotlin

Tags: android, regex, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use substringBefore() fun with two char ("#" and "&").
How can i use regex for both cahrs?
I dont want to do this:

```
if (myString.contains("&")) {            
    myString.substringBefore("&")    
} else if (myString.contains("#"))
    myString.substringBefore("#")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a way and it is actually easy:

```
 val matchRegex = "[#&]".toRegex().find(myString)
 val manipulatedString = matchRegex?.range?.first?.let {
   myString.substring(0, it)
 }
```

This will return NULL if there is no regex chars in the string or, the subString before those chars

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `substringBefore()` does not accept a regex parameter.  However, `replace()` does, and we can formulate your problem as removing everything from the *first* `&` or `#` until the end of the string.

```kotlin
myString.replace(Regex("[&#].*"), "")
```

The above single line call to `replace` would leave unchaged any string not having any `&` or `#` in it.  If desired, you could still use the `if` check:

```kotlin
if (myString.contains("&") || myString.contains("#")) {
    myString.replace(Regex("[&#].*"), "")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using RegEx:

If the result contains neither '&' nor '#' and you want the whole string to be returned:

```
val result = myString.split('&', '#').first()
```

If the result contains neither '&' nor '#' and you want *null* to be returned:

```
val result = myString.split('&', '#').let { if (it.size == 1) null else it.first() }
```

Not using RegEx:

If the result contains neither '&' nor '#' and you want the whole string to be returned:

```
val result = myString.takeWhile { it != '&' && it != '#' }
```

If the result contains neither '&' nor '#' and you want *null* to be returned:

```
val result = myString.takeWhile { it != '&' && it != '#' }
  .let { if (it == myString) null else it }
```